# storage class not specified in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int arr[5];

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

int main(){
        printf("\n %d \n",arr[0]);
        return 0;
}
```

Why is the array initialisation cant be performed outside the functions ?

Comment: You can, you just have to do it declaratively instead since you can't execute code outside of a function in C. Use `int arr[5] = {1, 2};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
```

This is not an initialization but an *expression statement*. Statements cannot appear at file scope.

To initialize your array:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2};
```

Answer (score 2):

Array initialisation **can** be performed outside a function, e.g.

```
int arr[5] = { 1,2 };
```

What you did is **not** array initialisation, but assignment to an array that was already declared.

Answer (score 1):

Your array initialization is actually an assignment, which has to be placed within a function.
An initialization looks like this:

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, };

int main(void)
{
}
```